# Which is the right scope to use?

Tags: coldfusion, scope

I am using ColdFusion 9.0.1

I am running a page that will include other pages. The main purpose of this page is to determine which page to include.  The pages that will be included will make use of the variable that I use in the page, which will be the MovieID (in this case).

My question is which is the best scope to use on this page? Would it be VARIABLES?

```
<cfscript>
Lookup = CGI.QUERY_STRING;
Query = CFC.doLookup(Lookup);
if (Query.RecordCount == 0) {
    include "Content/Home.cfm";
} else {
    // MOVIE PAGE
MovieID = Query.MovieID; // WHAT SCOPE SHOULD I USE HERE? FOR MOVIEID?
include "Content/Movie.cfm";
}
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes:**
Variables

**Maybe:**
Application, Cookie, Request, Server, Session

**No:**
Arguments, Attributes, Caller, CGI, Client, Flash, Form, Local, This
ThisTag, Thread, thread local, URL

For info about each scope, check the CF9 documentation: [scope types](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html).

Sounds like you're implementing a [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

Implement an Application.cfc, with an onRequest() that runs your code snippet. That way, it would intercept all incoming requests and include the appropriate cfm. Skipping the need for a handler index.cfm which simply includes the other cfm templates.

A further optimisation. Have your doLookup() method return a Struct containing just the recordCount + movieId as it appears that is all you are using. Returning a whole query is slower than just a struct of two numbers.

CF9 documentation: [Application.cfc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d39.html).

Comment: Thanks so much for the additional info (Wiki link), and the suggestion of moving the controller to the Application.cfc.  Now that you mention it, it's the perfect idea.  Thanks much!!!

Comment: Query.MovieID could also have been used and it would have been more or less read only.

Answer (score 3):

`Variables` (which is what you have now) certainly works.  Another reasonable option would be `Request`, but I would lean toward `variables` over `request`.

Comment: Jake, thanks for clarifying and confirming my thoughts.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Although either `Variables` scope or `Request` scope will be available to an included page, using `Request` scope could be helpful inasmuch as it is a scope that is intended to be available to any file in the request, whereas `Variables` scope is generally perceived to be specific to a given page.

In fact, `Request` scope was originally introduced for Allaire Spectra for the purpose of sharing variables across custom tags.

So, while both will do what you want, I would say that `Request` scope may have a small advantage of clarifying intent just a bit more.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like REQUEST may have a slight advantage.  Thanks for the info!